# Getting BPXWUNIX to use the users .profile along with the /etc/profile?

Tags: zos, rexx, omvs

Here is my sample code which works with BPXWUNIX and uses the `/etc/profile` but I can see no way to get the users `.profile` to be included. As you can see the `login` flag is set (that is the `1` at the end of the `bpxwunix` parameter string.

```
/* rexx */       
/* pass as an argument any OMVS command (i.e. env) */                               
parse arg cmd     
/* now get the users home (pwd) location */                              
address syscall 'getpwnam' sysvar('sysuid') 'h.'
/* place into the environment stem as HOME */
env.1 = 'HOME='h.4                              
env.0 = 1    
/* echo out the home and full command now */                                   
say 'home:' env.1                               
say 'cmd:' cmd  
/* issue the bpxwunix call */                                
x = bpxwunix(cmd,,s.,e.,env.,1)   
/* view the results */              
call stemedit 'view','s.'                       
call stemedit 'view','e.'
```

I'm using `stemedit` from [www.cbttape.org](http://www.cbttape.org) file 895 to view the stdout and stderr stems.

Comment: I did some more testing and a message that is generated by the /etc/profile is also generated in my ~/.profile so that confused me.  I added a unique message in my ~/.profile and using the bpxwunix with the login option does in fact invoke both system and user profiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working answer:

```
/* rexx */                                              
/* process the omvs command to execute */               
parse arg cmd                                           
/* get the users home directory (pwd) */                
address syscall 'getpwnam' sysvar('sysuid') 'h.'        
/* put into the bpxwunix environment variable */        
env.1 = 'HOME='h.4                                      
env.0 = 1                                               
/* issue the bpxwunix command */                        
x = bpxwunix(cmd,,s.,e.,env.,1)                         
/* view results using stemedit from cbttape file 895 */ 
call stemedit 'view','s.'                               
call stemedit 'view','e.'
```

Comment: i am probably blind, but can you highlight the difference between the two entries?